# How to copy raw text from website without using clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, clipboard, puppeteer

I have made a scraper with puppeteer which goes to a website presses
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and copies the text to a file.

Its a very simple script but it is very annoying that it uses the windows clipboard because if I let the script run in the background I cannot copy and paste anything.

Is there another way to copy the raw text from websites without using the windows clipboard? With *raw* text I mean all the text which you can see when you visit a website and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: you might want to look at multi-clipboard software like these https://windowsreport.com/clipboard-managers-windows-10/ or consider a different approach to scraping https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) value from `document.body`, which should contain the same (or at least very similar text) to what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would give you.

**Code Sample**

```js
const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerText);
```